# Design for mixed structure in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an object A, 
some fields in A I want them to be initiated at server start time only once, say A.a, A.b. 
some fields in A I want them to be initiated in dynamic memory since it's different per request.
I also have a bunch of objects B,C,D.. that has the same fields as A but with different values, most of them are the same as A, so I want to use inheritance,

The design I can think of:
separate A into 2 parts,
StaticA and A, and then

```
class A {
 public:
  StaticA* static_data();
  // other getters fo A.c, A.d...
 private:
  Tc c_;
  Td d_;
}
```

Then static A will be like

```
StaticA {
  public:
   //getter for A.a, A.b
  private:
   Ta a_;
   Tb b_;
}
```

Then since I want to use inheritance, the code becomes ugly since I need to have a base class for StaticA/B/C/D and also A/B/C/D, also I want to hide these details from the clients, so I will need to write redundant getter functions in A's class.

Is this right way to design? Is there other better way to implement such mix logic? Thanks!

Comment: "that has the same fields as A but with different values most of them are the same as A, so I want to use inheritance" Why inheritance? These sound like different instances of `A`, not subclasses.

Comment: @John3136 yeah right, sorry for the misleading words, I will have a base class so that A,B,C,D could all inherit from it, so that I can set the default value in the base class, and the subclasses will no need to override these values if they are the same.

Comment: Your words are clear. Your design is not. Why do you need subclasses at all? Why not just one class A and several instances of it?

Comment: If I have 100 fields in `A` then I need to pass in 100 parameter to the constructor if they are all `A` but with slightly different values?

Comment: If you have 100 fields in A then chances are you are doing it wrong - but that is a different question.